# Add a filter with OR using sqlalchemy in eve pre_GET hook

Tags: eve

I am using Eve with the sqlalchemy branch to develop a REST API.

I want to add a filter to a GET request before the request is sent to the database, however I have found no way to do this yet.

What I want to do is basically this:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_

def pre_GET(resource, request, lookup):
    lookup.append(_or('field1'==1, 'field2'==2))
```

Of course this does not work, as lookup is a dictionary. However searching to the eve source code I can see no possibility to realize an OR. The lookup variable is parsed with parse_dictionary() in this file: https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/sqlalchemy/eve/io/sql/parser.py

The corresponding way when using MongoDB would be this:

```
lookup['$or'] = [{'field1': 1}, {'field2': 2}]
```

However this only works with MongoDB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this is an old question.
eve-sqlalchemy is now an extension with separate lifecycle/code base.

Current code base seems to handle `or` condition [here](https://github.com/RedTurtle/eve-sqlalchemy/blob/master/eve_sqlalchemy/parser.py#L54)

May be it works now ?

---

Update (Feb 06, 2016)

I tested this. Following syntax works :

```
lookup['or_'] = [{'field1': 1}, {'field2': 2}]
```

Notice `or_` instead of `$or` you expected.

Comment: Yes, it has been patched. I figured out a solution back then, but I appreciate your answer.